# Reference for Atiyah-Hirzebruch SS and stunted projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, topological-k-theory

I would like to know if there are any textbooks on topological $K$-theory that explain the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence and use it to compute $KO$ of (real) stunted projective spaces. I know that Dugger's *A geometric introduction to K-theory* covers these topics, but there are many digressions and lacks a bit of formality (not in the sense that is not well-written, but I think its aim is to expose some topics to experienced readers, not to formally introduce the subjects). Right now my level in $K$-theory is at the long exact sequence / Bott periodicity / fundamental product theorem (basically the first three chapters of Randal-Williams *Characteristic classes and K-theory*); do you know any book that, starting from my level or below, introduces the two topics I mentioned, with patience and formality?

Update: I searched again more deeply but I keep finding only papers that seem already too advanced. At this point my question is: are there actual textooks that contain AHSS (for topological $K$-theory) and stunted projective spaces (even separately in two books) aside from Dugger's one?

Comment: (A comment, not an answer, since it's not quite what you're looking for:) Stunted projective spaces are cofibers of inclusions of projective spaces, yes? So can't you use the long exact sequence for a cofibration for these? Fujii has a paper where he computes the real K-theory of all real projective spaces and I think you might be able to deduce a lot of information from this. You can also likely put this information together with a long exact sequence that relates complex+real K-theory...

Comment: ... together (can retrieve a precise reference for you if you want, but it's somewhere in Karoubi's book). None of this involves the AHSS and I don't know any good reference for the AHSS and its applications to computing topological K-theory, but nonetheless you might be able to scrap together a computation with the above techniques.

Comment: can you say what was unreadable in Dugger's notes? Also do you know the complex story? I think you may need power operations (adams)